# && and 'and' are the same in php?

Tags: php, logical-operators

I tried the following code and got **&&** and **and** are different.

```
<?php

$keyWord =  2 and 3>4;

$symbol  =  2 &&  3>4;

echo $keyWord===$symbol ? 'equal' : 'not-equal';
```

output: not-equal

why?

Comment: Different operator precedence.

Comment: and && are same in the case of operation but different in case of precedence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They do not have the same precedence. Fully parenthesised, your code is:

```
($keyWord = 2) and (3>4); // $keyWord = 2
$symbol = (2 && (3>4)); // $symbol = false
```

`2` and `false` are clearly not the same, hence `'not-equal'`.

[More on operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: `$symbol = (2 && (3>4));` is this correct ?? I guess it should be `$symbol = (2 && 3)>4);`

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Erm... why?

Comment: `&&` has more precedence than `>`

Comment: `($keyWord = 2)` - isn't that an assignment?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Erm... no it doesn't!

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ: Absolutely. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Kolink : Why is that ? operator precedence says so please check the link : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @Kolink Pardon, I must admit I didn't read the question and thought this was asked related to comparison. +1 and sorry.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra The table clearly shows that `<` has higher precedence than `&&`.

Comment: ohhhh... I am sorry I got confused with assignment operators :) +1

Answer (score 3):

Well, altering the code slightly to:

```
<?php
$keyWord =  2 and 3>4;

$symbol  =  2 &&  3>4;

var_dump($keyWord);
var_dump($symbol);
?>
```

produces an output of:

```
int(2) bool(false)
```

As Kolink points out above, this is due to operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the precedence of logical operators (part of the table)

```
left    &&  logical
left    ||  logical
left    ? :     ternary
right   = += -= *= /= .= %= &= |= ^= <<= >>= =>     assignment
left    and
```

In your case :

```
case 1:

$keyWord =  2 and 3>4;

($keyWord =  2) and (3>4);
```

Here `$keyWord =  2`

```
case 2:

$symbol  =  2 &&  3>4;

$symbol  =  (2 && (3>4));
```

Here `$symbol = false`

**Solution** : `$keyWord =  (2 and (3>4));` and `$symbol  =  2 &&  (3>4);` Use brackets

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php